# Is the use of a half glove to reduce left-hand smudging a recent invention?

Tags: history

When looking at answering this question about [Dr. Kigner's half glove](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96283/what-is-dr-kibner-wearing-on-his-hand-and-why) in *Invasion of the Body Snatchers*, my first thought was that it was an anti-smudge glove. I wear one when working on my digital tablet to reduce fingerprints and palm-contact triggering the surface, and I remembered hearing of similar devices being used by left-handed writers to avoid smudging the ink when writing left-to-write, but much to my surprise, my searches seemed to indicate this was a recent invention of the early 2010s:

> It has been invented by Jeannie Lit from New Jersey, who struggles whenever she writes as her hand drags along the page and becomes covered in ink.
>
> When she realised her son was also left handed, she decided to invent something that could help him.
>
> She made a prototype by cutting up a sock and has now developed the product, which retails at £9.65 ($14.99).

Is this invention so recent, or is she just the first person to gain acclaim for marketing it?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Speculation on when an item of clothing was invented is not a graphic design question, so I'm voting to close this as off-topic. Sorry about that. But for what it's worth, sign writers and painters sometimes use a rest called a mahlstick (aka maulstick) to prevent accidental smudging of their work. It's probably been around for hundreds of years. It's not specifically made for left or right handers. I wouldn't think a glove would be that useful to be honest, except perhaps for digital tablet devices. A glove would still smudge real wet ink or paint.

Comment: @BillyKerr: That's fair. It seemed close enough, history of usage in the graphic arts, to fit for me, but I won't argue the point. :-D

Comment: **Smudge glove** is perhaps a more common term than "half glove".. and yes, they've been around for centuries. From what I know, artists have used them (along with maul-sticks) since art became a thing. `:)` For a tablet... I find a smudge glove exceptionally handy because I struggle to "hover while drawing"... although it's never around when I need it.

Comment: As for that quote... it's *marketing hype*.. she was definitely NOT the first person to invent such a thing. I'd speculate that "New Jersey" didn't even exist when the first smudge glove was used. It's akin to someone claiming to have invented the bucket, or the artist's hand-held palette.

Comment: @Scott: That's what I thought, but I'm having a hard time finding the right search terms to prove it.

Comment: Not really surprising. Their use is so ubiquitous that finding the *first* use would be challenging. Like finding the inventor of the bucket. `:)` You  may find a first reference.. but inventor is another matter. I can say, from personal experience, I purchased my first smudge glove in the early 1980s... well before 2010. And it was *not* a "new" thing at the time. You can find photos of Disney animators in the 50s using smudge gloves.

Comment: Janine whatshername appears to be marketing a *specific product* she claims to have invented. She may well have invented that *specific product* but she's not responsible for the *concept*. Dokiware has a "patent pending" similar in concept glove. In fact, there are dozens of similar gloves out there. You can't patent a *concept* but you can patent a specific creation - how the stitching works, the material, etc. I think *that* is what Janine whatshername is marketing.